# Sequence $\sin^2n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to prove that if $a_n = \sin^2(n),$ then it does not converge.

Usually we show 2 subsequences with different limits for those sine cases, but I could not do this since my n is a natural number and I cant construct those subsequences. How can I show, then, it doesn't have limit?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138959/convergent-subsequence-of-sin-n) for how to construct convergent subsequence of $\sin(n)$

Answer (score 5):

There is always an integer $a_k$ between $2k\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $2k\pi + \frac{3\pi}{4}$

Consider that sequence. $\sin^2 a_k > \frac{1}{2}$ for all $k$.

There is always an integer $b_k$ between $2k\pi + \frac{5\pi}{6}$ and $2k\pi + \frac{7\pi}{6}$

Consider that sequence. $\sin^2 b_k < \frac{1}{4}$ for all $k$.

Answer (score 3):

One way to prove it is to show that the sequence is not Cauchy. If it were Cauchy, you'd have

$|a_{n+1}-a_n|< \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ as long as $n$ is large enough. To show that this is not the case you can see that

$|a_{n+1}-a_n| = |\textrm{sin }(1+n)^2 - \textrm{sin }(n)^2|$ is not a sequence that goes to zero (Use the addition formula for sine).

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html

Comment: I dont get how to finish this, sorry

Comment: Expand out $\textrm{sin}(n+1)$ first. then square what you get. Finally subtract $\textrm{sin}(n)^2$ and you'll find that you can simplify! You'll get a trig function that does not go to zero.

Comment: I got $1/4 sin(2x) + 2 cos(1)sin(1) sin(2x) + sin^2(x)(cos^2(1)-1)$

Comment: I must be blind

Comment: So let's see, I got
$(\textrm{sin}(1)\textrm{cos}(n)+\textrm{sin}(n)\textrm{cos}(1))^2 = \textrm{sin}(1)^2\textrm{cos}(n)^2+\textrm{sin}(n)^2\textrm{cos}(1)^2 + 2 \textrm{sin}(1) \textrm{cos}(n) \textrm{sin}(n) \textrm{cos}(1)$ 

Notice there is a $\textrm{sin}(n)^2$ term!

Upon subtraction you get: that the only remaining term is the so-called cross term: $2 \textrm{sin}(1) \textrm{cos}(n) \textrm{sin}(n) \textrm{cos}(1)$

Comment: Yep, I got the same for now

Comment: So, do you still have a question? This function of $n$ Does not decay since it's proportional to $\textrm{sin}(2n)$.

Comment: Wait, how the cos^2 and sin^2 dissappeared when you subtract the sin^2 term?

Comment: Oops, I messed up, instead I get: $ \textrm{cos}(n)^2 \textrm{sin}(1)^2 + \textrm{sin}(n)^2 \textrm{cos}(1)^2 - \textrm{sin}(n)^2 = \textrm{cos}(n)^2 \textrm{sin}(1)^2 + (\textrm{cos}(1)^2 - 1)\textrm{sin}(n)^2 =  (\textrm{cos}(n)^2-\textrm{sin}(n)^2) \textrm{sin}(1)^2 $


       So you are left with something like  $A \textrm{cos}(2n) + B \textrm{sin}(2n)$. Still a function that does not go to zero at infinity.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot see how this is only a function of 2x, I mean, how the square cos and sin terms were canceled with the sin^2 term subtracted.

Comment: Wolfram gives a better form: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%5E2%28X%2B1%29+-+sin%5E2%28X%29&x=0&y=0 but I couldn't do the right steps to find it

Comment: You might be better off starting by applying the double-angle identity $\sin^2 x = \frac{1 - \cos 2x}{2}$ to both terms. (I mean, what you're doing now pretty much amounts to deriving that, so it should work if you get it right, but I think my way is easier...)

Answer (score 2):

Assume instead that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin^{2}n=L$.  Then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^{2}n=1-L$, and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin^{2}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos 2n)=L\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos 2n=1-2L$; so $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^{2}2n=1-L\implies(1-2L)^2=1-L\implies4L^2-3L=0\implies L=0 \text{ or } L=\frac{3}{4}$.

$\textbf{1)}$ If $L=0$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin n=0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^{2}n=1$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos 2n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\cos^{2}n-\sin^{2}n)=1\implies$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(2n+1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\cos 2n\cos1-\sin 2n\sin1\right)=\cos1\implies$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^{2}(2n+1)=(\cos1)^2=1,$ which gives a contradiction.

$\textbf{2)}$  If $L=\frac{3}{4}$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin^{2}n=\frac{3}{4}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^{2}n=\frac{1}{4}$, so

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(\cos(n+1))^2=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\cos n\cos1-\sin n\sin1)^2$

$\displaystyle=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\cos^{2}n\cos^{2}1-\sin 2n\sin1\cos1+\sin^{2}n\sin^{2}1)$

$\displaystyle=\frac{1}{4}\cos^{2}1-(\sin1\cos1)[\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin 2n]+\frac{3}{4}\sin^{2}1=\frac{1}{4},$

so
$\displaystyle(4\sin1\cos1)[\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin 2n]=\cos^{2}1+3\sin^{2}1-1=2\sin^{2}1\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin2n=\frac{1}{2}\tan1\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin^{2}2n=\frac{1}{4}\tan^{2}1=\frac{3}{4}\implies\tan^{2}1=3,\text  {which gives a contradiction.}$

Comment: The implication that lim cos2n = 1 - L is not true since the limit of cos2n does not exists. I mean, this implication could be write if we knew that this limit exists.

Comment: You are correct, but it follows from the (false) assumption that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin^{2}n$ exists. (I am using that $\cos 2n=1-2[1/2(1-\cos2n)]$.)

Comment: Why the limit of sin is 0 in the first case?

Comment: In the first case, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin^{2}n=0$, so this implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

It is known that if you step along a circle, with an irrational ratio between the length of your step and the perimeter of the circle, then the set of all points along your way is dense in the perimeter. In particular, if the length of your step is $1$, your going to be very close to both $\pi/2$ and $0$ infinitely many times. This is enough for the above series not to converge.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof without finding subsequences. Suppose that $\sin^2 n\to a$, $n\to\infty$. Then $\cos^2n\to1-a$. Since $\sin^22n=4\sin^2n\cos^2n$, taking limit we obtain $a=4a(1-a)$, so either $a=\frac34$ or $a=0$. In the first case $$\sin^23n=\sin^2n(3-4\sin^2n)^2\to 0,$$ a contradiction. In the second case $\sin n\to 0$ and $$\sin(n+1)=\sin n\cos 1+\cos n\sin 1\to 0,$$
so also $\cos n\to 0$, which obviously contradicts the basic trigonometric identity.

Comment: Why we have $\lim sin(n)=0$ in the second case?

Comment: @Giiovanna, $a_n^2\to0$ iff $a_n\to 0$ (it's easily seen from the definition, since $a_n^2<\varepsilon\Leftrightarrow|a_n|<\sqrt\varepsilon$).